# Backup SQL Server database remotely to a specific user shared restricted folder

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, backup, shared-directory

I want to back up other computers' databases on my network to a network-shared folder on its `C:\` disk remotely, the shared folder is only open to its own user.

It works fine if I give everyone permission to the shared folder, but I need to restrict it and I don't know how to do the code part.

Comment: If only one user can access that folder then most certainly the Service Account that SQL Server is running under isn't going to be able to access it; so therefore you need to grant the SQL Server Service Account access to that share/location. Then you'll be able to `BACKUP` to the (UNC) path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a backup copy of the database in a network path, the User that started the SQL Server service must have write access to that shared folder in the network path. Otherwise you will get an access denied error.